# Logical not operator

Tags: tcl

Coming from C/C++ land, I am wondering why the following does not work:

```
set a 111
if {! $a eq {} } {
  puts hi
}
```

I know if I change the 2nd line to `if { $a ne {} } {` then it is fine, but cannot wrap my head around why "!" does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because in Tcl, `!` has a higher precedence than `ne`, so it is evaluated first.

You can check out [this link](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm#M6) for a complete list of Tcl operator precedence.

Comment: yes, you are right, using () to group the eq expression solves the problem.